# Повтор дополнения с новым определением: пункутация

Tags: пунктуация

1. Я увидел чистый снег, искристый снег(,) и встал на лыжи.
2. Я увидел снег, чистый искристый снег(,) и встал на лыжи.

**Нужны ли взятые в скобки запятые?**
Я полагаю, что нужны, иначе воспринимается, будто в каждом случае по два разных снега, но не уверен, особенно во втором предложении.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Эта тема регулируется правилом Розенталя http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=104#pp104 § 16. Запятая при повторяющихся словах.

При этом Розенталь допускает **оба варианта** для подобных предложений:

Пункт 2. Если после повторяющегося слова (или словосочетания с ним) при чтении не делается паузы, то никакими знаками препинания от последующих слов в предложении это слово не отделяется: Мне страстно, до боли страстно захотелось оскорбить или унизить их (М. Г.); Лес, сплошной лес окружал нас со всех сторон;

Но если после повторяющегося слова (или словосочетания с ним) при чтении делается пауза, то после этого слова ставится запятая (иногда — тире) и весь оборот оказывается обособленным (выделенным запятыми с двух сторон): Прошло пять лет, пять долгих, тоскливых лет, со дня их последней встречи;

2. *Я увидел снег, **чистый искристый снег**, и встал на лыжи.* Здесь оборот желательно обособить, его интонационное выделение просматривается ясно.

*Я увидел чистый снег, искристый снег и встал на лыжи.* Здесь обособление нежелательно, пауза выглядит неестественно. Впрочем, все предложение с художественной точки зрения проигрывает первому.